# How to select Html Select List value in Controller MVC My Code Attached

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, listview, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

In view i have Jquery to shift select values from

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedQuestions, Model.Questions, new { id = "ChooseLeft",MultiSelectList=true })
```

to

```
 <select id="ChooseRight" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

and Jquery function i am using is ,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#ShiftRight,#ShiftLeft").click(function (event) {
            var ID = $(event.target).attr("ID");
            var ChooseFrom = ID == "ShiftRight" ? "#ChooseLeft" : "#ChooseRight";
            var moveTo = ID == "ShiftRight" ? "#ChooseRight" : "#ChooseLeft";
            var SelectData = $(ChooseFrom + " :selected").toArray();
            $(moveTo).append(SelectData);
            SelectData.remove;
        });
    });
</script>
```

It is working fine moving value leftlist to right list. But i am getting null value exception when i am trying to get value from rightlist in controller ,

```
string ListValue = Request.Form["ChooseRight"].ToString();
```

Hopes for your suggestion

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `Request.Form` collection indexer, you must add `name` attribute to the `<select>` element:

```
<select id="ChooseRight" name="ChooseRight" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

The reason to add `name` attribute is mentioned in [this MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985(v=vs.90).aspx):

> The `Form` collection is indexed by the **names of the parameters** (i.e. form elements) in the
>   request body. The value of `Request.Form[element]` is an array of all
>   the values of element that occur in the request body.

If you don't want to add `name` attribute manually, just create another `ListBoxFor` with different property to bind:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ChooseRight, null, new { id = "ChooseRight", MultiSelectList = true })
```

And then use `ChooseRight` property (with `List<string>` type) like this to obtain values:

```
string ListValue = string.Join(",", model.ChooseRight);
```

Working example: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WwsiFB)